# destructure and return multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, destructuring, map-function

I'm new on javascript and learning now destructuring.
What i'm trying to achieve(get shown in console) is this :

> "Name: Mike Smith, Father: Harry Smith"

> "Name: Tom Jones, Father: Richard Jones"

I'm getting error message that *n is not defined*  but it should be ok ?
here is my code what i have been doing :

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: 'Mike Smith',
    family: {
      mother: 'Jane Smith',
      father: 'Harry Smith',
      sister: 'Samantha Smith'
    },
    age: 35
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom Jones',
    family: {
      mother: 'Norah Jones',
      father: 'Richard Jones',
      brother: 'Howard Jones'
    },
    age: 25
  }
];

const kalle= people.map(( {name: n, family: {father: f}})=> { 
return [n,f]
});
  
console.log('Name: ' + n + ', Father: ' + f);

// "Name: Mike Smith, Father: Harry Smith"
// "Name: Tom Jones, Father: Richard Jones"
```

Comment: Your log is outside of your function, so no, your `n` is not defined here, `kalle` is.

Comment: You dont use kalle anywhere to access his properties. Since `f` and `n` have no global scope they are undefined.

Comment: @acincognito so how to fix it to get that result ("Name: Mike Smith, Father: Harry Smith"

"Name: Tom Jones, Father: Richard Jones")

Answer (score 1):

`n` and `f` are outside the function which means you can't acces them instead loop over the array.

Destructuring objects don't need a key unless the value is an object as well.

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: 'Mike Smith',
    family: {
      mother: 'Jane Smith',
      father: 'Harry Smith',
      sister: 'Samantha Smith'
    },
    age: 35
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom Jones',
    family: {
      mother: 'Norah Jones',
      father: 'Richard Jones',
      brother: 'Howard Jones'
    },
    age: 25
  }
];

// Returns an array
const persons = people.map(({name, family: {father}})=> { 
  return [name, father];
});

// Log each person
persons.forEach(([name, father]) => {
  console.log(`Name: ${name}, Father: ${father}`);
});

// "Name: Mike Smith, Father: Harry Smith"
// "Name: Tom Jones, Father: Richard Jones"
```

Comment: i could do it like this 'const kalle= people.map(( {name: n, family: {father: f}})=> { 
return console.log('Name: ' + n + ', Father: ' + f);
});'  but i want to have my log outside of function

Answer (score 0):

A simple `join` may match what you expect

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: "Mike Smith",
    family: {
      mother: "Jane Smith",
      father: "Harry Smith",
      sister: "Samantha Smith",
    },
    age: 35,
  },
  {
    name: "Tom Jones",
    family: {
      mother: "Norah Jones",
      father: "Richard Jones",
      brother: "Howard Jones",
    },
    age: 25,
  },
]

const kalle = people
  .map(({ name: n, family: { father: f } }) => {
    return "Name: " + n + ", Father: " + f
  })
  .join("\n")

console.log(kalle)
```